# Importance of verifying user email on web signup

Tags: security, email, registration, verification

I know this question is crazy - but my employers client is demanding that email verification be removed from the sign up process (they feel it is impeding sign up). 
I wanted to garner feedback from the programming community at large as to their experience and opinions regarding sign up and email verification - and the possible consequences of removing this safeguard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm on their side -- 95% of the time websites don't actually need an e-mail address, they just collect it because all the other web registrations they've seen collect one. If you're worried about spam, use a captcha; e-mails are a horrible way to stop automated registrations. With sites like [Mailinator](http://mailinator.com/) to give people instant throwaway e-mails and [BugMeNot](http://www.bugmenot.com/) to save people the hassle of dealing with registrations like yours, you should avoid making your registration any harder than it needs to be. Stack Overflow is a great example -- you don't even need to register to ask/answer questions

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that robots will not bother going through a registration process. Your average simple-minded robot simply spams into a form that requires no other action (authentication, identification) at all. The mere act of asking for one or more extra clicks will prevent most simple-minded "attacks." If you look at the blog site for Coding Horror, they use a captcha with a *constant* capture word.

On the other hand, while a few extra clicks will deter dumb robots, they will not deter human spammers, jokers, griefers, etc. But then again, throwaway email addresses are pretty easy to come by, so if someone truly wants to fill your site with junk they can.

My conclusion is this: I guess you will get about 10% to 20% more "junk" on your pages, and between 5% and 25% more "desired" accesses, depending on how badly it was bothering your potential customers. Thus, I don't see any big harm in removing the email barrier.

Answer (score 1):

Email is important to identify the user, for instance, when they forget their password. If email verification is setup in such a way that users are not able to log on until they verify their email address then I also think that it is impeding. The application should allow the user to log on and use the application and set it up so that the user needs to verify their email address in a fixed number of days, for example, a week. If they do not their account is suspended.

On the other hand if we have to remove the email verification then I think we would need to add a feature similar to the major email services that allow the user to reset their forgotten passwords in the absence of a valid email address.

Comment: they can logon to the system, they can get password reminders, they just can't access main features without verification

Comment: "...allow the user to reset their forgotten passwords in the absence of a valid email address." This is often done with a "security question," which is easier to guess than a password and therefore negates the value of the password. Think of it this way: you buy a magical, indestructible lock for your house and ask the locksmith, "what if I lose the key?" And he says, "oh, no problem, just jiggle any key in the lock for about a minute to rekey it." Yikes! If you can do that, a burglar can. Might as well not have a lock.